# TypeError: indexedDB.databases is not a function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

This script prints the contents of an IndexedDB.

When I run this script in website console it shows this:

[image: Error:]

I tried using IDBDatabase(), but then it's saying "Illegal constructor".

Can you point out my mistake?

Here's the code:

```js
const dumpIndexedDB = (dbName) => {
  const DB_VERSION = 1;
  const req = indexedDB.open(dbName, DB_VERSION);
  req.onsuccess = function () {
    const db = req.result;
    const objectStoreNames = db.objectStoreNames || [];

    console.log(`[*] Database: ${dbName}`);

    Array.from(objectStoreNames).forEach((storeName) => {
      const txn = db.transaction(storeName, "readonly");
      const objectStore = txn.objectStore(storeName);

      console.log(`\t[+] ObjectStore: ${storeName}`);

      // Print all entries in objectStore with name `storeName`

      objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = (event) => {
        const items = event.target.result || [];
        items.forEach((item) => console.log(`\t\t[-] `, item));
      };
    });
  };
};

indexedDB
  .databases()
  .then((dbs) => dbs.forEach((db) => dumpIndexedDB(db.name)));
```

Comment: What browser are you using? According to MDN (in regards to `IDBFactory.databases()`):

"This method is introduced in a draft of a specifications and browser compatibility is limited."

Comment: @tromgy Im using Firefox

Comment: That's the problem. This function is not implemented in Firefox. It works in Chromium and Safari though.

Comment: Did you find a Firefox alternative to enumerate the locally stored databases?

Comment: @HOH_HOH any of you found a replacement for that `.databases()` on firefox?